# How can I prevent the garbage collector from tampering with a memory allocated to a delegate

Tags: .net, multithreading, c++11, asp.net-web-api, garbage-collection

We have a .NET web api controller in c# from which I create a background thread to call a long running method in a dll. the long running method gets a delegate as a parameter. it seems like after a while that delegate is being collected which leads to an access violation exception. How can I prevent the garbage collector from collecting/rewriting that memory?

Thanks

Comment: You normally put the delegate in a static variable: `static SomeDelegate MySomeDelegate = ...`. If you look around it is explained in many places.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/25973343/613130